# For loop issue with Bluetooth devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect my phone to a HN-06 Bluetooth Module for Arduino.
I'm using a for loop to add every bonded device to a ListView:

```
mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set pairedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();

if (pairedDevices.size() > 0){
    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + 
        device.getAddress());
    }
}
```

But when I do this I get an error in the BluetoothDevice device telling me they are

> Incompatible types, Required: Object, Found: Bluetooth Device.

How can I solve this?

Pd. mBtAdapter is declared right under the class in the following way:

```
private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the type of object for your Set

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices
```

You can also remove the `if (pairedDevices.size() > 0){` since the loop takes care of that